# How to compose Logstash geo_point out of longitude and latitude

Tags: json, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am not able to compose a geo_point in Logstash by combining latitude and longitude. I followed and instructions made by others, but it looks like that those examples are based on older versions of ELK. Since ELK 2.2 there is a major change regarding geo_point and I am not sure whether I performed all the steps in the right way. Down here I explain my setup.

The version of ELK I use is:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200' 
{
"name" : "Artie",
"cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
"version" : {
"number" : "2.2.1",
"build_hash" : "d045fc29d1932bce18b2e65ab8b297fbf6cd41a1",
"build_timestamp" : "2016-03-09T09:38:54Z",
"build_snapshot" : false,
"lucene_version" : "5.4.1"
},
"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

A use a [Elasticsearch](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/), [Logstash](https://hub.docker.com/_/logstash/) and Kibana on Docker containers, but that should not matter.

This is how my logstash.conf looks like:

```
cat logstash.conf
input {
    http_poller {
            urls => {
                   myresource => "myhost/data.json"
            }
            request_timeout => 1
            interval => 1
            # Parse every line captured from data.json as a new event. 
            codec => "line" 
    }
}
filter {
    if [message] !~ /\"hex\":/ { 
        # drop messages without "hex"
        drop {} 
    }
    # Capture "hex":72d5a1
    grok {
            match => { "message" => "\"hex\":\"(?<hex>[^\"]+)\"," }
    }
    mutate {
            convert => { "hex"       => "string"  }
    }
    # Capture "lat":50.047613
    if [message] =~ /\"lat\":/ {
        grok {
                match => { "message" => "\"lat\":(?<latitude>[^,]+),"}
        }
        mutate {
                convert => { "latitude"  => "float"   }
        }
    }
    # Capture "lon":1.702955    
    if [message] =~ /\"lon\":/ {
        grok {
                match => { "message" => "\"lon\":(?<longitude>[^,]+)," }
        }
        mutate {
            convert => { "longitude" => "float"   }
        }
    }
    # convert latitude and longitude into location.
    mutate {
        rename => {
                "longitude" => "[location][lon]"
                "latitude" => "[location][lat]"
        }
    }
    mutate {
        remove_field => [ "message" ]
    }
}
output { 
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => [ "elasticsearchhost:9200" ]
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" 
    }  
}
```

The important part is that "lon" & "lat" were captured from the "message" and that they are formatted as "location" field.

When I query elasticsearch I get this kind of records:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2016.04.04",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "AVPieJtgVkabtr-H2szZ",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-04-04T18:11:07.857Z",
    "hex": "3e37aa",
     "location": {
      "lon": 4.8246,
      "lat": 52.329208
   }
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1459793467857
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1459793467857
  ]
}
```

The notation `"location": { "lon": 4.8246, "lat": 52.329208 }` looks good, from what I read in the documentation. But the thing is that I can not  select the field "location" as geo_point in Kibana.

According the ELK documenation I need to be sure that the "location" field is mapped to the geo_point type. It requires that doc_values are enabled in order to function. I am not sure whether I should do something, because when I look in my template it looks like the "location" field is already mapped by default: `"location" : { "type" : "geo_point", "doc_values" : true }`

This is how my template looks like:

```
# curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template/logstash?pretty
{
 "logstash" : {
  "order" : 0,
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "5s"
      }
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "_default_" : {
        "dynamic_templates" : [ {
          "message_field" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "fielddata" : {
                "format" : "disabled"
              },
              "index" : "analyzed",
              "omit_norms" : true,
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "match_mapping_type" : "string",
            "match" : "message"
          }
        }, {
          "string_fields" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "fielddata" : {
                "format" : "disabled"
              },
              "index" : "analyzed",
              "omit_norms" : true,
              "type" : "string",
              "fields" : {
                "raw" : {
                  "ignore_above" : 256,
                  "index" : "not_analyzed",
                  "type" : "string",
                  "doc_values" : true
                }
              }
            },
            "match_mapping_type" : "string",
            "match" : "*"
          }
        }, {
          "float_fields" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "float",
              "doc_values" : true
            },
            "match_mapping_type" : "float",
            "match" : "*"
          }
        }, {
          "double_fields" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "double",
              "doc_values" : true
            },
            "match_mapping_type" : "double",
            "match" : "*"
          }
        }, {
          "byte_fields" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "byte",
              "doc_values" : true
            },
            "match_mapping_type" : "byte",
            "match" : "*"
          }
        }, {
          "short_fields" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "short",
              "doc_values" : true
            },
            "match_mapping_type" : "short",
            "match" : "*"
          }
        }, {
          "integer_fields" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "integer",
              "doc_values" : true
            },
            "match_mapping_type" : "integer",
            "match" : "*"
          }
        }, {
          "long_fields" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "long",
              "doc_values" : true
            },
            "match_mapping_type" : "long",
            "match" : "*"
          }
        }, {
          "date_fields" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "date",
              "doc_values" : true
            },
            "match_mapping_type" : "date",
            "match" : "*"
          }
        }, {
          "geo_point_fields" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "geo_point",
              "doc_values" : true
            },
            "match_mapping_type" : "geo_point",
            "match" : "*"
          }
        } ],
        "_all" : {
          "omit_norms" : true,
          "enabled" : true
        },
        "properties" : {
          "@timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "doc_values" : true
          },
          "geoip" : {
            "dynamic" : true,
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
              "ip" : {
                "type" : "ip",
                "doc_values" : true
              },
              "latitude" : {
                "type" : "float",
                "doc_values" : true
              },
              "location" : {
                "type" : "geo_point",
                "doc_values" : true
              },
              "longitude" : {
                "type" : "float",
                "doc_values" : true
              }
            }
          },
         "@version" : {
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "type" : "string",
            "doc_values" : true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "aliases" : { }
  }
}
```

I did not add something to this template. This is how it looks like after a fresh install of Logstash and Elastic and launching Logstash with my logstash.conf file.

My question is: What steps do I need to take in order to solve my issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The "location" field in your template is really "[geoip][location]" but your data is in "[hex][location]".  As such, the magic of the template is not being applied to your field.  Either move your data to [geoip][location] or change the template.

Also, it would be more efficient to parse your message in one regexp rather than first running the regexp in the conditionals and then running it again in the grok patterns.

Comment: Updated answer to be more explicit.